# How to add static image in Bigcommerce product detailed page

Tags: php, templates, woocommerce, customization, bigcommerce

I want to put an image on product detail page of bigcommerce. I want it to 
be visible on certain categories, so I need a PHP condition to get the category ID and show that static image on that certain category.I am new to Bigcommerce , I 
khow php but do not know how to restrict an image on certain category. Please if
any body know or can guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to read through the BigCommerce API docs to get everything set up (like tokens) if you haven't yet, for the categories and images, [look here](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/categories#update-a-category). And [here are the product docs, so you can see how to update images for specific products](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/products).

As you can see, you can make a GET call to `/api/v2/categories` to list categories, and if you want to update a category with an image, you can make a PUT call to `/api/v2/categories/{id}` and pass in the `image_file`, which will be a URL to the image. If you're unsure how to make API calls to BigCommerce, [you should probably start here](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api).

Comment: Actually I solved this by adding templates for products, mean I created a different template for the products where I need a static image.